# Zurb Foundation 4 default body font-size changing causes layout width issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

My requirement is, if a developer type some text anywhere on the web page without a specific tag (`<p>`, etc) the font size should be same as `<p>` tag's font-size.

In `foundation.css` I've changed the `html,body { font-size:0.85 }`. With this edit, the whole layout (whole site template) is getting shrink. Increasing the size is causing vice-verse.

Is there any other way to introduce our own default body font-size to foundation safely without harming the template?

Is there any suggestions to achieve my requirement without introducing a new font-size attribute to the content wrapping div?

Comment: use !important for other elements or follow the [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Comment: Thanks. New values are reading by the browser. Problem is when changing body font size whole page width is getting affected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Zurb uses the font size that you have specified in the html, body {} style to calculate the width of the site. Whatever you set the font-size value to becomes 1em throughout the site. If you look further down in the css you will find a definition for .row {} which looks something like max-width: 62.5em.

As you can imagine, when you make the value of 1em smaller, that 62.5em value for rows is going to get smaller as well. I don't know much about modifying it with the css version of zurb as I have always used the sass gem but you can adjust the number of ems for the row width.

Try:

desired site width / body font-size in px = number of ems your row max-width should be.

e.g.

If you want 960 width with a base font size of 12px

960 / 12 = 80

So you would set you row max-width to 80em.

I'm sure someone better qualified will come along and give a better answer but that is how I understand the grid.

Comment: this is from the docs: // Since the typical default browser font-size is 16px, that makes the calculation for grid size.
// If you want your base font-size to be different and not have it effect the grid breakpoints,
// set $em-base to $base-font-size and make sure $base-font-size is a px value.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you aren't using sass, so this won't help this particular person, but **if one were using sass**, take note of this comment in the foundation source code of `components/_variables.scss`:

> the typical default browser font-size is 16px, that makes the
>   calculation for grid. **If you want your base font-size to be
>   different and not have it effect the grid breakpoints**, set $em-base
>   to $base-font-size and make sure $base-font-size is a px value.

(emphasis added)

so before you import any or all of foundation sass files, you would write something like this:

```
$base-font-size: 12px;
$em-base: $base-font-size;
```

note: "the typical default browser font-size is 16px" from the above. Foundation uses normalize.css, and that normalize will set that as a default.

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify `foundation.css` but instead define your own style in your own "separate" css file. If you do this for example:

```
body {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

And have the following layout, you will see that the grid still responds to the width of your device/browser.

```
<div class="large-12 columns">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Four columns</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Four columns</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Four columns</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/SADkk/)

Comment: problem is when increasing body font-size, the whole site's width is getting increased. I've noticed the `.row` default width is connected with the body font-size. Don't know how to break the connection between them. or playing with the body font-size without affecting to the .row width

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean maybe an example would help.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean inckka, any attempt to control base size is shrinking the layout and text. It's so annoying - this sort of customisation should be easy as peanuts to do.

Comment: @JCraine you can post an issue you are having and I'm sure the community can help. I've tried changing the base font size and it works okay. Maybe there's a specific scenario where it doesn't work, would be interesting to see.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on how to increase the body size (paragraph-size) - I edited the variable in the global scss file, but the Ps in the recompiled version are smaller than the default where the base size was 16px. Is there anything else I need to be changing?

Comment: Rule will be ignored in Foundation 5, superset by for example a p font-size 1 rem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of would to be create a wrapper element around your content areas (or the whole page) and changing the font size as follows:

```
<div class="content">
<p>My stuff</p>
<a href="#" class="button">A button</a>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.content * {
font-size: 90% !important;
}
```

Untested, but I'm fairly certain I've done something similar in the past.